# Where Can I Find Current Adobe Image Format Specifications? "Clipping Paths"

Tags: c#, gdi+, path, irb, clipping

This is in regards to Adobe's Image Resource Blocks(**IRB**), that they store in TIFF, PSD, JPEG Formats. It's also called "**8BIM**", This standard was released with Adobe's Photoshop 3 (November 1994).

IRB contains information on color profiles and clipping paths(what i am interested in).

The only piece of documentation i can find on the internet is [this 4 page document](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/photoshop/psir/ps_image_resources.pdf) provided by Adobe in 1990.

I have been searching *imagemagick* source code to find that the IRB ID's for clipping paths are from 2000 to 2998, to thats a usable 998 clipping paths.

So I managed to get a IRB Byte Array of each resource block from JPEG and a TIFF file, specified in the four page document. I rolled my own and tested out [Graphics Mill](http://www.aurigma.com/Products/GraphicsMilldotNET/default.aspx) to see if managed to get the same information.

I am not sure how to convert the clipping path byte array into anything usable since I don't even know the format that adobe photoshop uses. The idea was to map the clipping path to a c# GDI+ Graphics Path.

I think that it's kind of pathetic that adobe has been around for so many years being the industry leader in graphic design, but yet they can't even provide necessary documentation.

**Can anybody suggest any documentation that i could use?**

Answer (score 1):

Barely it's still actual for you, but some info can be found here
http://www.adobe.com/devnet-apps/photoshop/fileformatashtml/PhotoshopFileFormats.htm

Answer (score 0):

+1 to mistika

Adobe specification contains description of PSD clipping path. The last revision is dated by Oct 2013 and looks like Adobe is currently working on it. At least I have feeling that new stuff was added.

If you are looking for a code using PSD format, take a look into [libpsd](https://github.com/alco/psdump/tree/master/libpsd-0.9). That’s a nice open source, pretty easy to read. Sometimes more informative that spec.

As for [GraphicsMill](http://www.graphicsmill.com/), since 6x version [it can transform](http://www.graphicsmill.com/docs/gm/M_Aurigma_GraphicsMill_Codecs_ClippingPath_Path_CreateGraphicsPath_2_22dcb54d.htm) Adobe Clipping Path to GdiPlus GraphicsPath.